# Simple jQuery fade-in when document loads / no user interaction should be required

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

Platform: ASP.NET 3.5, ASP.NET Ajax intermixed

I'm very green to jQuery, so have been having a hard time with what I assume to be trivial.

All I need to do is create the following scenario

1. user logs in to my site, and I take him/her to a 'dashboard'
2. I want a nice little bar to 'fade in' with some information I want to draw his/her attention to

The examples on jQuery seem to suggest I need to click something to make it happen - but I don't want any user interaction. User logs in, user sees a nice fadein info bar. That's it.

I saw a few examples and can't get it to work and I have tried both the following:

(1)

```
  $(document).ready(function () {           
           $("#fadein").fadein("slow");           
   });
```

(2)

```
$("#fadein").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn(); });
```

My div is as follows

```
<div id="fadein" style="display:none;">this will fade in now yeah</div>
```

(PS - I have tried with  display:none and without it. Made no difference)

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong? Just in case it helps

- I moved the  from the contentpage to the masterpage, made no difference

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first should work, just fix the function name which is [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) instead of `.fadein()`:

```
$('#fadein').fadeIn('slow');
                 ^
```